# Android how to stream video to remote server

Tags: android, streaming, android-video-record

I have to build a live stream app, where I get the input video from an external device (a glasses with a camera) and broadcast that stream to a remote server. The input stream consist in a steam of bitmap, and this stream is also displayed in a view in my MainActivity. My idea was to capture the screen, or part of it, and than upload that portion.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think we will use something like WebRTC

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem